# How to implement Post-Build stage using Jenkins Pipeline plug-in?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-workflow, jenkins-pipeline

After reading Jenkins [tutorial](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/) explaining [Pipeline](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Pipeline+Plugin) plug-in, it seems that plug-in should make it possible to implement **Post-Build** steps. However documentation is rather limited in regard to specific instructions.

For example I wonder how to implement:

> - Run only if build succeeds
> - Run only if build succeeds or is unstable
> - Run regardless of build result

- *Run only if build succeeds*

  ```
  stage 'build'
  ... build
  ... tests
  stage 'post-build'
  ...
  ```

  (Or add `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=false` to the `MAVEN_OPTS`)
- *Run only if build succeeds or is unstable*

  ```
  stage 'build'
  ... build
  try {
      ... tests
  } catch {
      ...
  }
  stage 'post-build'
  ...
  ```

  (Or add `-Dmaven.test.failure.ignore=true` to the `MAVEN_OPTS`)
- *Run regardless of build result* - could it be done using `try / catch / finally` ?

  ```
  try {
      stage 'build'
      ...
  } catch {
      ...
  } finally {
      stage 'post-build'
      ...
  }
  ```

(I've noticed that final build status is set as **SUCCESS** even though some stages, ie. 'build', have failed as it set based on last stage. Does that mean final build status need to explicitly set, ie.`currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE'`? )

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I assure that a Jenkins pipeline stage is always executed, even if a previous one failed?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37463489/how-do-i-assure-that-a-jenkins-pipeline-stage-is-always-executed-even-if-a-prev)

Answer (score 56):

The best way is to use post build action in the pipeline script.

> Handling Failures
>   Declarative Pipeline supports robust failure
>   handling by default via its post section which allows declaring a
>   number of different "post conditions" such as: always, unstable,
>   success, failure, and changed. The Pipeline Syntax section provides
>   more detail on how to use the various post conditions.

Jenkinsfile (Declarative Pipeline)

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh 'make check'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            junit '**/target/*.xml'
        }
        failure {
            mail to: team@example.com, subject: 'The Pipeline failed :('
        }
    }
}
```

The documentation is below
https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post

Comment: this doesn't work for me when i am running it in Pipeline project

Comment: @Mohamed, as Subrat said, this doesn't work outside of the jenkins file. Is there another way to do it?

Comment: It could be due to the jenkins version or plugin version however I am not sure. The other way to do it is put the changes in a try catch and finally block.

Comment: @MohamedThoufeeque do you know if you can make the posy steps conditional? I would like to only send an email if the build fails for certain branches.

Comment: how do you get the stage where the failure happened in the post directive? is that an environment variable?

Comment: this is working perfect for me, we can use the `success` on the post too.

Comment: The POST actions are executed based on `currentBuild.result`. Is there any way to execute those post actions based on `currentState.result`??

Answer (score 7):

FWIW, if you are using scripted pipelines and not declarative, you should use a `try/catch/finally` block as suggested in the other answers. In the `finally` block, if you want to mimic what the declarative pipeline does, you can either put the following directly in the block, or make it a function and call that function from your `finally` block:

```
def currResult = currentBuild.result ?: 'SUCCESS'
def prevResult = currentBuild.previousBuild?.result ?: 'NOT_BUILT'

// Identify current result
boolean isAborted = (currResult == 'ABORTED')
boolean isFailure = (currResult == 'FAILURE')
boolean isSuccess = (currResult == 'SUCCESS')
boolean isUnstable = (currResult == 'UNSTABLE')

boolean isChanged = (currResult != prevResult)
boolean isFixed = isChanged && isSuccess && (prevResult != 'ABORTED') && (prevResult != 'NOT_BUILT')
boolean isRegression = isChanged && currentBuild.resultIsWorseOrEqualTo(prevResult)

onAlways()
if (isChanged) {
    onChanged()
    if (isFixed) {
        onFixed()
    } else if (isRegression) {
        onRegression()
    }
}
if (isSuccess) {
    onSuccess()
} else {
    if (isAborted) {
        onAborted()
    }
    onUnsuccessful()
    if (isFailure) {
        onFailure()
    }
    if (isUnstable) {
        onUnstable()
    }
}
onCleanup()
```

The various `onXYZ()` calls are functions that you would define to handle that particular condition instead of using the nicer syntax of the declarative `post` blocks.

Comment: I just tried this and found cases where some stage errors (error added on purpose to test the post build step) can't be detected... currResult == SUCCESS when the job is clearly failing (Jenkins literally write in the console `Finished: FAILURE`). in my finally block, both currentBuild.result & currentBuild.currentResult are SUCCESS. Any idea why?

Comment: @MoOx sorry I'm just seeing this now ... it has been ages since I looked at this, and perhaps something has changed internally with how the current result of the build is handled. Would have to test it, but you may need to use `def currResult = currentBuild.currentResult ?: 'SUCCESS'` instead in the first line. I forget which is set by Jenkins and which is set from your Groovy code, but if memory serves, `currentResult` may be what is required here. It may not have been set, so you can assume `SUCCESS` in that case. If there was a failure, it would be set to `UNSTABLE` or `FAILURE` already.

Comment: @MoOx also, I would have to see specifically how your code is written, where the `try/catch/finally` is placed, and where the error condition is coming into play. Debugging pipelines, in my experience, is far from fun, but not impossible. Just takes being able to see the code as a whole and being able to run it on my Jenkins instance.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using try/catch and you want a build to be marked as unstable or failed then you must use currentBuild.result = 'UNSTABLE' etc.  I believe some plugins like the JUnit Report plugin will set this for you if it finds failed tests in the junit results.  But in most cases you have to set it your self if you are catching errors.

The second option if you don't want to continue is to rethrow the error.

```
stage 'build'
... build
try {
    ... tests
} catch(err) {
    //do something then re-throw error if needed.
    throw(err)
}
stage 'post-build'
...
```

Answer (score 3):

`try-catch` blocks can be set up to handle errors like in real application code.

For example:

```
try {
    node {
        sh 'sleep 20' // <<- can abort here
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    println 'catch'
} finally {
    println 'finally'
}

node {
    println 'second'
}

try {
    node {
        sh 'sleep 20' // <<- can abort here again
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    println 'catch'
} finally {
    println 'finally'
}
```

And here is an example output with two aborts.

```
Started by user me
Replayed #3
[Pipeline] node
Running on my-node in /var/lib/jenkins-slave/workspace/my-job
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[my-job] Running shell script
+ sleep 20

Aborted by me

Sending interrupt signal to process

/var/lib/jenkins-slave/workspace/my-job@tmp/durable-9e1a15e6/script.sh: line 2: 10411 Terminated              sleep 20
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] echo
catch
[Pipeline] echo
finally
[Pipeline] node
Running on my-node in /var/lib/jenkins-slave/workspace/my-job
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] echo
second
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] node
Running on my-node in /var/lib/jenkins-slave/workspace/my-job
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
[my-job] Running shell script
+ sleep 20

Aborted by me

Sending interrupt signal to process
/var/lib/jenkins-slave/workspace/my-job@tmp/durable-d711100c/script.sh: line 2: 10416 Terminated              sleep 20
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] echo
catch
[Pipeline] echo
finally
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: ABORTED
```

Of course, this works for any exceptions happening during the execution.