# How do I assure that a Jenkins pipeline stage is always executed, even if a previous one failed?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am looking for a `Jenkinsfile` example of having a step that is always executed, even if a previous step failed.

I want to assure that I archive some builds results in case of failure and I need to be able to have an always-running step at the end.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I hope this question would be helpful, http://stackoverflow.com/q/36651432/6128602.

Answer (score 20):

We switched to using Jenkinsfile Declarative Pipelines, which lets us do things like this:

```
pipeline {
    agent any
    stages {
        stage('Test') {
            steps {
                sh './gradlew check'
            }
        }
    }
    post {
        always {
            junit 'build/reports/**/*.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

References:

[Tests and Artifacts](http://Reference:%20https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/tour/tests-and-artifacts/)

[Jenkins Pipeline Syntax](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/)

Comment: If you use a docker container as an agent, this won't run the post within the container :(

Answer (score 10):

```
   try {
         sh "false"
    } finally {

        stage 'finalize'
        echo "I will always run!"
    }
```

Comment: how do you do this in a pipeline script?

Comment: @AndrewMyhre that is pipeline script syntax so you can copypaste that into your pipeline definition.

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is to use a [`parallel`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel) section in combination with a [`lock`](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/lockable-resources/). For example:

```
pipeline {
    stages {
        parallel {
            stage('Stage 1') {
                steps {
                    lock('MY_LOCK') {
                        echo 'do stuff 1'
                    }
                }
            }
            stage('Stage 2') {
                steps {
                    lock('MY_LOCK') {
                        echo 'do stuff 2'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Parallel stages in a parallel section only abort other stages in the same parallel section if the fail fast option for the parallel section is set. See [the docs](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#parallel).

Comment: The order in which these steps will be executed might be random.

Comment: I checked some runs, and they all execute the stages in order of the Jenkinsfile

Answer (score 0):

When a Jenkins stage fails, all of the rest starts and ignore message. So stages are skipped but you really want them to run. You can use the catchError block to catch errors and continue with the pipeline. Here’s an example:

```
stage('Example') {
    steps {
        catchError(buildResult: 'SUCCESS', stageResult: 'FAILURE') {
            sh './run-my-script.sh'
        }
    }
}
```