# How to add a post build action in the pipeline in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

Below is my pipeline script

```
node(Slave01) {
currentBuild.displayName = "${URL_Name}"
}
stage 'Pt2ctf process'
node(Slave01) {
build job: 'Pt2ctf_16_7', parameters: [string(name: 'URL_Name', value: "${URL_name}"), string(name: 'Display_Name', value: "${Display_Name}")]
}
stage 'add_fields'
node(Slave01) {
build job: 'add_fields_16_7', parameters: [string(name: 'URL_Name', value: "${URL_Name}")]
}
```

The above groovy script would trigger multiple builds in sequence. I have another build to be run once the sequence is completed. I don't see any post build option in the pipeline job configuration.

Is it  possible that we can add few more lines like below:

```
post
node(Slave01){
build job: 'testing_build'
}
```

Or do we have any other option? please suggest

Comment: Guys can anyone please suggest

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651432/how-to-implement-post-build-stage-using-jenkins-pipeline-plug-in

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Post-Build stage using Jenkins Pipeline plug-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651432/how-to-implement-post-build-stage-using-jenkins-pipeline-plug-in)

Answer (score 6):

You can simply add `post` action to your pipeline script, in case of using declarative pipeline.
It is explained in [Pipeline syntax reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post).

Comment: @Vadim Kotov
Can you drop me a snippet  ? 
And the other job(example: job2) should run after pipeline completes all builds internally. Nothing should be in parallel.

I have tried but i get this error : java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'post' found among steps

Comment: @Vadim Kotov 
for pipeline: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'pipeline' found 

I am using ""Pipeline configuration Job"

Comment: @SubratSahoo, here is a code snippet as well: https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post. Maybe, you made some syntax mistake that's why you are getting error?

Comment: i have made the correct steps, but this doesn't support my requirement. When i give post build, it runs for each parameter that i pass. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can add a stage for post build to add post build action in pipeline:

```
stage 'post-build'
node(Slave01){
build job: 'testing_build'
}
```

You can use this stage as:

```
try {
    //Stages to be included in build
    ...
} catch {
    ...
} finally {
    stage 'post-build'
    ...
}
```

Comment: this is not my requirement. I need to add a post-build for the pipeline but not another post build stage
post build is to trigger another job outside the pipeline