# Groovy + Jenkins + Perforce

Tags: jenkins, groovy

I have a groovy script to send notifications. I need to run this as post build after each of my job in jenkins. I need to do this without manually updating each job.

Problems faced:

1. Tried to make this as jenkinsfile. But Pipleine script from perforce is buggy and cannot be used.

Any suggestions??

Comment: what is "buggy"?

Answer (score 0):

You can run a script after any job using plugins. [Post build task](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Post+build+task) this plugin will be useful in your case. No manual work needed after configured.

Comment: When there are hundreds of jobs, it is tough to go add the groovy script to each job. Is there any alternative?

Comment: If you are familiar, you can do that by `pipeline scripting`. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227997/how-to-add-a-post-build-action-in-the-pipeline-in-jenkins](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43227997/how-to-add-a-post-build-action-in-the-pipeline-in-jenkins).