# Jenkins post build script in pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline setup in Jenkins server. After a job runs on the pipeline I would like a post-build script to push build artifacts back to a GitHub repository. Any references on how to do this ??
Thanks

Comment: More info required, Declarative or Scripted pipeline?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to implement Post-Build stage using Jenkins Pipeline plug-in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36651432/how-to-implement-post-build-stage-using-jenkins-pipeline-plug-in)